# Scraping Python script returns None

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.7

im trying to scrape data from amazon in particular the product title but running my script only returns None

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Inspiron-5570-Touchscreen-Laptop/dp/B07FKRFTYW/ref=sxbs_sxwds-deals?keywords=laptops&pd_rd_i=B07FKRFTYW&pd_rd_r=38a464f1-5fc2-4e1e-91a3-c209f68e2b8c&pd_rd_w=IbLEX&pd_rd_wg=l5Ewu&pf_rd_p=8ea1b18a-72f9-4e02-9dad-007df8eca556&pf_rd_r=SWJJFWF3WM0ZQZGMN8XA&qid=1562328911&s=computers-intl-ship&smid=A19N59FKNWHX7C'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' }


page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle")

print(title)
```

expected results should be the div containing the product Title but instead None is the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to comment but I wanted to leave a note on what @Fozoro said in case someone in the future runs into the same issue I did. doing pip install lxml ran successfully however when I was attempting to use it as the parser for my application it still gave me errors about not finding the requested feature. however, doing:
`python3 -m pip install lxml` allowed me to work with the lxml parser.

Answer (score 0):

Change your parser:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Inspiron-5570-Touchscreen-Laptop/dp/B07FKRFTYW/ref=sxbs_sxwds-deals?keywords=laptops&pd_rd_i=B07FKRFTYW&pd_rd_r=38a464f1-5fc2-4e1e-91a3-c209f68e2b8c&pd_rd_w=IbLEX&pd_rd_wg=l5Ewu&pf_rd_p=8ea1b18a-72f9-4e02-9dad-007df8eca556&pf_rd_r=SWJJFWF3WM0ZQZGMN8XA&qid=1562328911&s=computers-intl-ship&smid=A19N59FKNWHX7C'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' }
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
title = soup.find(id="productTitle")
print(title.text)
```

---

You can also extract from `content` attribute of one of the meta tags

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Inspiron-5570-Touchscreen-Laptop/dp/B07FKRFTYW/ref=sxbs_sxwds-deals?keywords=laptops&pd_rd_i=B07FKRFTYW&pd_rd_r=38a464f1-5fc2-4e1e-91a3-c209f68e2b8c&pd_rd_w=IbLEX&pd_rd_wg=l5Ewu&pf_rd_p=8ea1b18a-72f9-4e02-9dad-007df8eca556&pf_rd_r=SWJJFWF3WM0ZQZGMN8XA&qid=1562328911&s=computers-intl-ship&smid=A19N59FKNWHX7C'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' }
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.select_one('[name=description]')['content']
print(title)
```

Comment: bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?..... that's what was returned , is there a library im missing?

Comment: lxml needs to be installed or use my bottom script

Answer (score 0):

You should start by installing [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/index.html) (if you don't have it already), you can do so using the following `pip` command:

```
pip install lxml
```

once installed replace this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') 
title = soup.find(id="productTitle")

print(title)
```

with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')    
title = soup.find(id = "productTitle")

print(title.getText().strip())
```

hope this helps